# Is it possible for a parent element to Inherit height from an absolutely positioned child element?

Tags: css, html

Is it possible for a parent element to inherit the height from a child element that is positioned absolutely?

Currently, I have `<div id="parent">` with `position: relative;`. Inside this "parent" is another element `<div id="child">` with `position: absolute;`.

> The issue I'm facing is that the "child" element is not forcing the "parent" element to inherit it's height, in turn causing page layout problems.

Comment: You'll have to use Javascript for this one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Absolute positioned elements aren't in the normal flow of the document, so they don't increase parent's height.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and
>   thus takes up no space when placing other elements.

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position):

> Absolutely positioned boxes are taken out of the normal flow. This
>   means they have no impact on the layout of later siblings.